# How can i determine the formula for determining the first number in Java's loop array for floyd's triangle?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Hi so i have java loop problem.

So i'm trying to figure out how to determine the first number(in the top of the pattern) in the loop for floyd's triangle by entering the height on the triangle.

Note: only the height is to be inputted to determine the first number and the last number should be fixed to 1.

for example:

```
Enter the height: 5

The first number is: 15

15
14 13
12 11 10
9  8  7  6 
5  4  3  2  1
```

Another one is

```
Enter the height: 6

The first number is: 21

21
20 19
18 17 16
15 14 13 12
11 10 9  8  7
6  5  4  3  2  1
```

I've figured out how to do the pattern and the decrementing of the value but i cant seem to figure out the first number. I've been trying to figure out the sequence but it's still confusing to me because i'm still new at java.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n;
        int startingnumber = ;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the height of the triangle: ");
        n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("The first number is "+startingnumber);

        for(int i =1; i<=n; i++){

            for(int j =1; j<=i; j++){
                System.out.print(startingnumber);
                startingnumber--;
            }

            System.out.println();
        }


    }
}
```

The code is still not finished because i cant figure out the formula :(

I would appreciate any help that i can find. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mathematical problem is [Triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) and here is a [visual demonstration](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/runsums/triNbProof.html)

```
S1 = 1
S2 = 1 + 2
S3 = 1 + 2 + 3
...
Sn = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n

=> 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n * (n + 1) / 2
```

An also have a look at [System.out.printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;
    int startingnumber;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the height of the triangle: ");
    n = input.nextInt();
    startingnumber = n * (n + 1) / 2;
    System.out.println("The first number is " + startingnumber);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d ", startingnumber);
            startingnumber--;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter the height of the triangle: 6
The first number is 21
 21 
 20  19 
 18  17  16 
 15  14  13  12 
 11  10   9   8   7 
  6   5   4   3   2   1
```

Comment: It worked! But how did you figure out the formula? I was trying to solve this for the past 3 hours but you instantly figured it out. Is there any way that i can get the formula for math stuff like this?

Comment: @Brian Usually you start with the basic examples `S1 = 1`,  `S2 = 1 + 2` and then try to deduce a generic formula `Sn = 1 + 2 + 2 + .. + n` or `n * (n + 1) / 2`

Answer (score 0):

The way you solve that type of question is by finding a mathematical relationship. In this case, you know (when input's 6) that the height's 6. You also know that at each row, you have one less number than at the one that goes after it. The bottom one has 6, as its the same as the height.

Therefore, you need to do 6+5+4+3+2+1 to obtain the starting number.

Now that formulated as a generic solution: n+(n-1)+((n-1)-1)..+1.

A possible implementation for that is:

```
System.out.print("Enter the height of the triangle: ");
n = input.nextInt();
int startingNumber = 0;
for (int i=n;i>0;i--) startingNumber+=i;
```